# ¿Como hacer un pipe Filter en Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

En la versión de Angular 2 quitaron el `pipe Filter` que filtraba cualquier coincidencia en cualquier propiedad de una lista de objetos, en la documentación dice que si necesita un `pipe Filter` pues que lo fabriquemos, pero no se como hacer esto.

Lo que necesito es:

```
 <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="buscar"></ion-searchbar>
 <div *ngFor="let producto of productos | Filter: buscar ">
     <div> {{producto.nombre}} </div>
     ...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel, buenas, te dejo un ejemplo que vengo usando para tablas simples de filter:

```
transform(values: [], value: string): string { 
    let ret = [];
    let columns = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(values[0]);
    let encontrado = false;


    if(value == '' || value == undefined){
      return values;
    }

    for(var i in values){
      encontrado = false;
      for(var x in columns){
        if(values[i][columns[x]].toUpperCase().indexOf(value.toUpperCase()) > -1 && !encontrado){
          encontrado = true;
          ret.push(values[i]);
        }
      }
    }

  return ret; 
  }
```

Ejemplo funcional en plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/AuqQjgb6ik2uhXZVMUey?p=preview

Un ejemplo un poco mas complejo que permite operaciones mas complejas: http://plnkr.co/edit/QegiCiqxhcKAaxmCvrjv?p=preview

Espero que te sea de utilidad, y cualquier duda, pregunta todo lo que necesites.

Comment: te paso la versión que hace eso, y además controla caracteres especiales, en un rato actualizo el ejemplo